# Partial view error when main view is requested

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have a view which display information about a store, at the bottom of this view is a partial view which renders particular promotions for that store in question.

On this view I render the logo for the given store using the below snippet

```
<div class="controls">
     <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.RetailerImage)" width="80" height="80" />
</div>
```

Now when I run it the partial view that loads the promotions throws an error

**An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.**

My partial at the bottom of the view

```
 <fieldset class="well">
       @Html.Action("ListRetailerPromotions", "Promotion", Model)
  </fieldset>
```

which calls this controller

```
   [AuthorizeRolesAttribute(RoleType.Retailer, RoleType.Administrator)]
    public ActionResult ListRetailerPromotions(Retailer retailer)
    {
        PromotionViewModel pvm = new PromotionViewModel
        {
            RetailerId = retailer.RetailerID,
            Promotions = UnitOfWork.Promotion.GetPromotionsForRetailer(retailer.RetailerID).ToList()
        };

        return PartialView(pvm);
    }
```

But when I get the yellow screen of death as some would say the error message is displayed as

**The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.**

But if I comment the partial view out all works as exspected.

**UPDATE**
I got it to work by setting the RetailerImage to null after is has been referenced as follows

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="WebAddress">
                    Preview
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.RetailerImage)" width="80" height="80" />
                </div>
            </div>
            {
                Model.RetailerImage = null;

            }
</div>
```

Which is a revolting solution I have to admit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Raw` on your image string

```
@System.Convert.ToBase64String(@Html.Raw(Model.RetailerImage))
```

If you see the error message, it complains about non-base 64 characters.

This means the framework has HTML encoded the contents of `Model.RetailerImage`. One way of preventing this default behavior is to use the `Raw` feature.

Comment: While this may answer the question, adding a brief explanation as to why or how it works would be helpful as well!

Comment: No problem, let me add more info :)